# C# Linq multi OR

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I want to optimize my query call by not calling 10.000 times (realistic number) the same query.

```
   var myObject= _db.myObject.FirstOrDefault(x => x.property1 == param1 && x.property2 == param2 && x.property3 == 3);
```

**So I thought**

Lets pass a list of myOtherObject to a function. The myOtherObject contains the fields that normally fill param1,2 and 3.

In a normal query I would create a string in a foreach and concat it. Like this:

```
            // WHERE (property1 = param1 && property2 = param2 && property3 = param3) OR (property1 = param1 && property2 = param2 && property3 = param3) OR (property1 = param1 && property2 = param2 && property3 = param3)
```

How can I archieve (if possible) the same in LINQ. **Is it possible to concat multiple ORs**

Ofcourse I tried concat with any and tried where's but that didnt work since it create AND statements (logically).

**Context**

I've a object in my own database. That I need to compare to another object in a database i've only read-only access rights on. I can match the two objects on a combination of 3 params.

**INPUT**

**List** of ObjectA (which has the 3 fields required to match)

**OUTPUT**

From the other (read-only) database I want a **List** of matched objects back.

Comment: Why don't you create a parametrized Stored Procedure in your DB and use that? This is a perfect use case.

Comment: I can only read from this database. I'm not sure if a stored procedure will get accepted. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: sorry to say, but didnt what you have as input what you want as output, always try to focus on your input/output when you're asking a question what will give us an idea what you have done and how we should done.

Comment: @DeepakSharma I completly forgot the context, mondays.. its coming

Comment: @JochemQuery: From my experience you usually get more acceptance if you demonstrate a performance boost of >1000% ;-)

Comment: @Robert thats a valid point. It's that i'm creating it now (and it's for an update method, so its not directly visible). So I guess if they complain I will say I need a stored procedure. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people facing this issue in the future : I solved this using linq contains

```
public async Task<List<MyObject>> GetMyObjectByListOfStrings(List<string> search)
    {
        var myObjects = await _db.Entity.Where(x => search.Contains(x.param1+ x.param2+ x.param3)).ToListAsync();
        return myObjects;
    }
```

There are probably better options, designs that should be changed or actual problems that should be fixed instead.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can build an expression for LINQ using [`System.Linq.Expressions` APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), a simpler approach may work, depending on the selectivity of the individual attributes in the target database.

First, note that the task of finding matches to a set of in-memory objects is very simple if the other set is also in memory:

```
// Type parameters of Tuple<,,> depend on the types of Prop1..Prop3
var expect = new HashSet<Tuple<string,string,string>>(
    targetList.Select(item => Tuple.Create(item.Prop1, item.Prop2, item.Prop3))
);
var matches = sourceList
    .Where(item => expect.Contains(Tuple.Create(item.Prop1, item.Prop2, item.Prop3)))
    .ToList();
```

Since the above would not work in a database search, consider a two-stage approach:

1. Read the database to find all possible matches with "false positives"
2. Filter out false positives using the approach described above.

You can obtain the list of items with false positives by querying for individual parameters, like this:

```
var p1List = targetList.Select(item => item.Prop1).ToList();
var p2List = targetList.Select(item => item.Prop2).ToList();
var p3List = targetList.Select(item => item.Prop3).ToList();
var preliminary = dbContext.BigTable
    .Where(item => p1List.Contains(item.Prop1)
                && p2List.Contains(item.Prop2)
                && p3List.Contains(item.Prop3))
    .AsEnumerable();
```

This approach will work as long as the DB query pares down the list to less than ten times the size of the actual result, because the in-memory query is very efficient in terms of its CPU usage (its efficiency is O(M+N), where M is the size of the list with false positives, and N is the size of the target list.

Comment: @JochemQuery You are welcome! I am curious if you had a chance to give it a try, and if there has been any success with this approach?

Comment: I had an exam instead of internship today (which i passed :)) so I didnt check yet. I am not sure when I try this approach but i will update here